# Почему не отправляется сообщение с встроенной кнопкой?

Tags: python, aiogram

Aiogram

```
@dp.message()
async def forward_to_admin1(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           "text")

    kb = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="text", url='google.com')
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=kb)

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Пользователь {message.from_user.first_name} написал:\n\n{message.text}\n\n", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

```
inline_keyboard.0.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='text', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.0.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='text', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.1.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='url', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.1.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='google.com', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.2.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='callback_data', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.2.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.3.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='web_app', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.3.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.4.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='login_url', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.4.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.5.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='switch_inline_query', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.5.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.6.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='switch_inline_query_current_chat', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.6.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.7.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='switch_inline_query_chosen_chat', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.7.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.8.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='callback_game', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.8.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.9.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value='pay', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
inline_keyboard.9.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardButton [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/model_type
```

Я не могу понять проблему. Я пытаюсь сделать это по типу поддержки. Человек пишет запрос, администратор нажимает кнопку и отправляет сообщение пользователю. Я не понимаю, почему происходит ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приходит не то, что ожидается

По [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/inline_keyboard_markup.html#aiogram.types.inline_keyboard_markup.InlineKeyboardMarkup) `InlineKeyboardMarkup` должен содержать список, у вас приходит строка:

> class aiogram.types.inline_keyboard_markup.InlineKeyboardMarkup(*, inline_keyboard: List[List[InlineKeyboardButton]], **extra_data: Any)
> inline_keyboard: List[List[InlineKeyboardButton]]
> Array of button rows, each represented by an Array of aiogram.types.inline_keyboard_button.InlineKeyboardButton objects

Скорректировал ваш код:

```
@dp.message()
async def forward_to_admin1(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           "text")

    kb = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="text", url='google.com')
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[kb]]) #here

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Пользователь {message.from_user.first_name} написал:\n\n{message.text}\n\n", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял у тя aiogram 3x в нём это вот так должно выглядить

```
@dp.message()
async def forward_to_admin1(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           "text")

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="text", url='google.com')
    ]])

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Пользователь {message.from_user.first_name} написал:\n\n{message.text}\n\n", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

у тебя не правильно клавиатура создана была прост

Comment: Спасибо, большое